# How to generate a database table from a .csv file automatically?

Tags: database, csv, create-table

I have a CSV file with 110 columns.
Preparing a table with 110 columns manually will take me forever.  Is there any other way to do it?

I tried to create a table , but I was wondering if there is any way that when I create a table in putty session, it takes the column names and number of columns by itself.

Comment: Which database management system are you using? Oracle? DB2? H2? Postgres? MySQL?

Comment: PuTTY is just a terminal -- telling us which terminal program you use tells us nothing about what software you're running on the other end, which is what we'd need to know to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you jump the gun and just make one huge table, you should sit down and think about if having one massive table really is useful in the long run.  Normalization can be a wonderful thing, and depending on the size of your input it would be much less of a hassle to structure everything now rather then later.

As far as deciding what to import, toss it into excel or mysql and drop the fields you don't want/need.  Mysql will actually build the structure of your table from the csv file, as long as you give it the right delimiter (comma, semicolon, whatever seperates your fields).

Comment: My business analyst does not which which rows to drop? Do you think that we can break 1 file into 5 small files..? Do we do it with a Map reduce program??

Comment: Well there are really 2 ways to break it down conceptually:
1) Literally just split the file into 5 smaller files and upload all of those to the same table
or 2) Figure out each row's reliance on other rows and split the table that way.  A good tutorial on starting that process can be found here http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/2/